# owl carousel slide n by n

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel, owl-carousel-2

Using **[owl carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/basic.html)** and trying to slide items five by five, now i have 5 items, i want when i push next or prev button it move to next five item, currently it move to next item, is it possible?

```
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    items:5,
    margin:10,
    nav:true
})
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/w3ka3vqw/150/)

i googled and checked plugin website but couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`slideBy`](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#slideby) options in the `owlCarousel` config:

```js
$('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
    loop:true,
    items: 5,
    margin:10,
    slideBy: 5, // slide 5 items
    nav:true
})
```

```css
.item {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/css/docs.theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><h4>1</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>2</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>3</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>4</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>5</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>6</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>7</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>8</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>9</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>10</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>11</h4></div>
    <div class="item"><h4>12</h4></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You should include `slideBy: 5` or `slideBy: 'page'` option, as they describe it on their [documentation](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/docs/api-options.html#slideby).

https://jsfiddle.net/w3ka3vqw/151/